# C#6/C++ ref keyword error

Tags: c#, c++, interop, roslyn, ref

I tried VS2015 with my exisiting solution and I get some valid new errors (like unreachable code that the compiler didn't catch before), but I also get an error for example on this line:

```
bool bWasAlreadyLocked = false;
oEnv.LockDoc(oWarnings, oEventDoc, ref bWasAlreadyLocked);
```

I get the following error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'ref bool [mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]' to
>   'ref bool [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'

I cannot see why it would throw that error, obviously the types do match. Is this a bug in the new compiler or has the behaviour of the `ref` keyword changed?

The function in this case is a C++ function which is imported to C# using a c# class derived from the c++ class. It's signature is this:

```
void CBkgDocEnvX::LockDoc(
CFIWarningList ^oWarnings,
CBaseDoc ^oBaseDoc,
// Output
bool %rbWasAlreadyLocked)
```

It might be good to mention that I opted to use the VS2013 c++ compiler for the c++ sources in the solution for now, so the c++ side *should* be the same as before. My guess is that something in the interop between c# and c++ changed.

Comment: What is the signature of `LockDoc`?

Comment: Looked it up, it's a C++ function

Comment: And `%` seems to be a c++ tracking operator. Not sure how to handle it in C#.

Comment: Hmya, that's a bug.  You do need to consider that the error message can be bugged too.  A C++ bool isn't the same as a managed bool, you *might* get ahead by declaring it as a System::Boolean instead.  Although it isn't clear whether you are using C++/CX or C++/CLI.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report beta bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately I have this issue all over the place, even with my own types. Sent a report.

Comment: @manuFS: can you post an answer (or comment, if an answer's not apropos) with a link to the Connect report?

Comment: My guess is (if it isn't a bug), that `bool %rbWasAlreadyLocked` gets compiled to a modified type (`modreq` in CIL) and these types are generally incompatible with C#. Could you upload the assembly somewhere?

Comment: @LThode I sent the report over the feedback button, not sure if that turns up anywhere.

Comment: @IllidanS4 It's a corporate project so I can't upload the assembly, also I'm not even sure it does produce an assembly since it doesn't compile.

Comment: @manuFS: you should be able to search for it on connect.microsoft.com...

Comment: I can't find a search feature on that site and when I go to "submit a bug" it says I am not authorized to do that (I am logged in). Microsoft at it's best! \o/

Comment: What version of .NET are you using in the C# Project?

Comment: By the way, that is C++/CLI.  The tracking reference is not allowed on bools in C++/CX, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this error can be fixed by explicitly adding an out attribute to the parameter.

Adding `[Out]` to the `ref` parameter apparently helps the new C# compiler to recognize that these are the same types and accept them. The methods in our interop solution now look like this:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

...

virtual void LockDoc(
   CFIWarningList ^oWarnings,
   CBaseDoc ^oBaseDoc,
// Output
   [Out] bool %rbWasAlreadyLocked
   ) override;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check this point just to be sure.

1. Only L-values may be passed by reference. L-value are variables and other expressions  that may appear in left-hand side of an assignment. These include including locals, field accesses, pointer dereferences, and array element accesses. L-values do not include property accesses, which do not have an identifiable machine address, nor do they include read-only fields, which are restricted by the CLR.
2. Ref parameters can not be the target of an extension method. Extension methods calls are expensive for value types, because the “this” parameter is copied by value. This also means that value types can’t have mutable extension methods. This is in direct contrast to instance methods, which pass the value type “this” parameter by reference.
3. Ref parameters can not be used in operator overloading functions.

You can find more information [here](http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2013/11/in-parameters-proposal-for-c-60.html).

Comment: That all sounds sensible, but not new. As the code works in VS2013 I doubt that it is caused by one of those cases, but do correct me if I'm wrong. Also, you can see the ref parameter declaration above.

Answer (score 1):

I get those kinds of compiler errors when two projects are of incompatible types. Often times Visual Studio will allow me to add a reference to a Portable Class Library project (or .NET 4.0 project) even when the assembly being referenced is not supported by the referencing project's .NET profile type.

The most common occurrence for me is when using a .NET 4.0 project and trying to reference a Probable Class Library project that specifies .NET 4.5 in its profile settings rather than the older .NET 4 version. When I reference the PCL assembly from my .NET 4.0 project I continue to get full intellisense support (e.g. when editing the source code intellisense will display all the namespaces, classes and properties contained inside the assembly being referenced) But at compile time I get the same kind of error you're getting; more specifically when I compile the solution the compile indicates a library mismatch, but lists the exact same library, version, and public key it says it's looking for.

Check the project properties, verify they're compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an Object data type instead of Boolean. After that you could parse it to Boolean.

Comment: Or I could not use VS2015 while this doesn't work instead of removing typing at hundreds of places throughout the project ;)